# Intuitive interpretation of the U-shaped Jakes Spectrum

Tags: wireless-communication

I was wondering if there is an intuitive interpretation for the Jakes spectrum? If I look at it in the time domain, which is basically the Bessel function zeroth order, it gives me a reading, how long the channel impulse response stays coherent i.e. phase and amplitude don't vary significantly. Or how long it takes, till the channel is decorrelated however if I look at the Jakes spectrum, the only thing which I can 'see' is how large the Doppler spread is but I can't get my head around, how should I interpret the amplitude (the y-axis). Does it mean, that the frequency components which are closer to the maximum shift are more prominent? And if so, is it just because of the Fourier transformation and there is no way to intuitively understand it?

Comment: Did you get the answer? Can you share it?